# How to check if the user waited 10 seconds to enter password on phone?

Tags: android, security, time, passwords, device-admin

I'm developing a security app, I need to check if someone waited for 10 seconds to enter a password on the android phone. How to do that? I was trying with this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final SendEmailTask sendEmailTask = new SendEmailTask();
                sendEmailTask.execute();
            }
        }, 10);
```

But didn't work. Any solution please?

Comment: You can save the Timestamp, first when your activity ends to be created, and second when user does the onClick to the login. Then you can count if has passed 10 secounds.

Comment: I want to count the time just when the user turn on the mobile screen, and waited for 10 sec but didn't do anything. In that case I want to send an email. Any code for this elpful. :)will be h

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the second parameter takes milliseconds.

Then, since 10 sec == 10000 ms :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final SendEmailTask sendEmailTask = new SendEmailTask();
            sendEmailTask.execute();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: 1000 = 1 second. Therefore 10000 is 10 seconds. Just so you are aware how that works.... if you were not understanding (for nabila)

Comment: i understand that, and this 10 worked in another case, so I think that was okay. :) I actually wanted to know how to get the waited time when the android phone screen is turned on, and in that on-screen mode just after 10 seconds it can perform an action, like sending email.